# How to call jQuery from controller(after sign up path from Devise)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, controller

I don't know is it possible - to call jQuery when user sign up.

I'm using Rails and Devise gem, so I have after_sign_up_path:

```
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path(current_user)
    //call jQuery 
 end
```

or if this is impossible - why my js is not working :

```
   if($('.alert').val()=='Welcome! You have signed up successfully.')) 
      $('#congrats').show();
```

**EDIT: HTML**

```
      <div class="alert alert-notice">Welcome! You have signed up successfully.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra `)` in your code:

```
 if($('.alert').val()=='Welcome! You sign up.')) 
                                //  -----------^
```

Try this:

```
if ( $('.alert').val() == 'Welcome! You sign up.' ) {
      $('#congrats').show();
}
```

for div elements you should use `text()` instead of `val()`:

```
if ( $('.alert').text() == 'Welcome! You have signed up successfully.' ) {
      $('#congrats').show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work( I just hate myself, because I made this working and later somehow lost file.

Comment: @DenMed are you sure value is exactly `Welcome! You sign up.` with no whitespace.

Comment: Yes. Maybe it should be another name of class ?

Comment: @DenMed what is the notice class? please show how if statement is executed.